# Unable to migrate AWS project without organization to within organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, migrate

Want to migrate "cia-project" to the "nl-plus.co.jp" organization.

[image]

Assigned an IAM role that seemed necessary for the project or organization, but access was denied.

[image]

> Denied access
> You do not have the following permissions required to
> perform this operation:
> "resourcemanager.projects.update"

Are there any roles missing?

- IAM role on the project side to be migrated

  - "Owner"
  - "Project IAM Administrator"
  - "Move project"
  - "Delete project"
- IAM role in the destination organization

  - "Owner"
  - "Project IAM Administrator"
  - "Move project"
  - "Project creator"
  - "Organization Administrator"
  - "Organization Policy Administrator"